# Can I use setuptools without permissions to /usr/local etc

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to use some packages (i.e., IPython or [zdaemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zdaemon/2.0.4)), butI am doing this on a system (my university) that does not give me permissions for /usr/local, /usr/bin, or all these directories. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use a [configuration file](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#configuration-files) that specifies an alternate installation directory, or use the `--install-dir` option. The standard place to put Python packages in your own user account is, I think, in `$HOME/.local/` (if you're using Python 2.6). So for instance, pure-Python packages will wind up in `$HOME/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`.

If your version of setuptools is recent enough to support it, also have a look at the `--prefix` option.

Comment: Actually, I don't see an --install-dir option, I do see --prefix.

Comment: `--prefix` is probably better anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--install-dir` option.  You need to make sure this directory is in `PYTHONPATH`.  You may find the [documentation](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Other Option is using virtualenv to help, if available

$ virtualenv myenv
$ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv)$ easy_install mycoolpackage

now it will end up in myenv subdir
to re-activate, just call the source line above
and to deactivate it, just close the terminal or
(myenv)$ deactivate
$