# setuptools error python27 setup.py install: Read-only file system

Tags: django, python-2.7, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to install Django on the Bluehost account. I used these instructions ([http://devget.net/misc/installing-django-1-5-1-with-python-2-7-4-on-bluehost/][1])

I've installed Python2.7.4. 
I went on to install setuptools:

> cd ~ 
>   wget --no-check-certificate http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz
>   tar xzvf setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz cd setuptools-0.6c11

The file is getting downloaded, but when I try to setup:

> python27 setup.py install
>
> I receive this error:  running install error: can't create or remove
>   files in install directory
>
> The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in
>   the installation directory:
>
> ```
> [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-800.write-test'
> ```
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix,
>   or the distutils default setting) was:
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
> ```
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If
>   the installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need
>   to sign in as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have
>   administrative access to this machine, you may wish to choose a
>   different installation directory, preferably one that is listed in
>   your PYTHONPATH environment variable.
>
> For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
>   documentation at:
>
> http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html
>
> Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

The odd thing is that /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ directory does not exist! I only have /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

How do I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

setuptools tries to perform system-wide (root) installation on the shared hosting. This is how setuptools acts by default. Because you do not have root access it is not possible.

If the host has any `virtualenv` command available use it. [Here are short guidelines how to perform local Python installations with virtualenv, without root](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/).

Here are local setuptools installation options in the case you cannot get virtualenv'ed environment bootstrapped for some reason:

[Can I use setuptools without permissions to /usr/local etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893787/can-i-use-setuptools-without-permissions-to-usr-local-etc)